# check if the second element of tuples in list of tuples are all the same

Tags: python

I would like to check if the second element of tuples in list of tuples are all the same

```
features = [(a,b), (c,b), (a,d)]
```

The first element of the tuple can be different.

```
x = []
for feature, geom_type in features:
    x.append(geom_type)
y = collections.Counter(x)
print len([i for i in y if y[i]>1])
```

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet?

Comment: What have you done so far ? Do you have a specific problem ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are overcomplicating matters. All you need is a set, then test if the set contains just one element:

```
len({g for f, g in features}) <= 1
```

The `{expr for targets in iterable}` construct is a [set comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-sets-and-dictionaries); it builds a set from all the second elements in your tuples. It'll only hold the unique elements; if it's length is not 1 then there were at different values.

If `features` is very large, you may want to bail out early rather than iterate over all elements; some [`itertools`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) magic could do that:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

def unique(it):
    it = iter(it)
    try:
        next(dropwhile(lambda e, f=next(it): e == f, it))
    except StopIteration:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

then use as:

```
if unique(g for f, g in features):
```

The `dropwhile()` returns the next element that is not equal to the very first value in the `it` iterable. If there is no such element, `StopIteration` is raised and we know the whole iterable contains just the one value. If no `StopIteration` was raised we found evidence it wasn't unique.

It'll also return `True` if there are no elements in `it` at all.

Demo:

```
>>> features = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'b'), ('a', 'd')]
>>> len({g for f, g in features}) <= 1
False
>>> unique(g for f, g in features)
False
>>> features = [('a', 'b'), ('c', 'b'), ('a', 'b')]
>>> len({g for f, g in features}) <= 1
True
>>> unique(g for f, g in features)
True
```

Comment: Note that this will give you a `False` result in the case that `features` is an empty list - that may be what you want, but it doesn't follow the convention used by `all()` and `any()`. If you did want the empty list to pass, simply make it `<= 1`.

Comment: @Lattyware: good one; the `unique()` iterable works like `all()` and `any()`; it'll return `True` for the empty iterable.

Answer (score 1):

For *very long* lists, it is not efficient to build a complete set as you are able to abort as soon as a "non-match" is encountered. In that case, a plain old imperative loop is to be considered:

```
def check_if_second_are_same(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if item[1] != lst[0][1]:
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: The first `len(lst)` is not really needed, as you'll end up at `return True` at the end if there is nothing to loop over. If `lst` is *large*, then don't use slicing to create a whole new copy minus the first element.

Comment: It's worth noting that while this is lazy, it does still require a sequence (meaning it's not memory-efficient unless you already have a list going in - likely to be a problem if your iterable is as large as you are talking about). Martijn Pieter's lazy solution works on arbitrary iterables without requiring it all to be in memory at once. The use of `dropwhile()` also avoids a slower Python loop in favour of a native implementation.